# Multiple button panel (bootstrap)

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, mdbootstrap

I am trying to implement a panel of buttons in bootstrap, which are displayed in a matrix formation on desktop and collapse to a single column on mobile.

I am hoping that when button (X) is clicked, options (forms etc) corresponding to (X) are displayed in window (Y).

Here is my humble attempt at illustrating my requirements:

```
 --- --- --- 
| X | X | X |
 --- --- --- 
| X | X | X |
 --- --- --- 
| X | X | X |
 --- --- --- 
|           | 
|           |
|     Y     |
|           |
|           |
 --- --- ---
```

In so far I have not managed to implement a solution which is close to what I desire. I have messed around with bootstrap accordions, but I cannot manage to configure them to work with multiple columns where window (Y) remains the full page width.

I would really appreciate any suggestions or example pieces of code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick...

```
<button>OwO</button>
<button>OwO</button>
<br>
<button>OwO</button>
<button>OwO</button>
<button>OwO</button>
<br>
<button>OwO</button>
<button>OwO</button>
<button>OwO</button>
<br>
<button id="big-boi">UwU</button>
<style>
  button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;

  }

  #big-boi {
    width: 180px;
    height: 150px;
  }
</style>
```

result:
https://web-platform-qkicup.stackblitz.io